# in Visual Studio 2019, what project runs when I press F5?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I's been a while I'm working with Visual Studio. so I'm a little confused. When the solution has 2 projects, (one send, the other receive), if I press F5 key, how can I tell what project will run?  Of course I can explicitly select the project by right clicking the project, and select debug, and select start new instance. In my solution browser window, the 'send' project name is in bold character. I thought it's bold because I once set it as the initial project. When I press F5, is it the 'initial project' that runs?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019

Comment: thanks I checked the document you pointed me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bold project is the one that launches when you press F5. To swap that, you can choose the option "Set as startup project" in the context menu of any project that is currently not active.

Note that you'll get an error if the startup project is not runnable when you press F5 (such as when the current startup project is a library). What exactly happens when you launch a project also depends on the settings on the "Debug" page of the project preferences. By default, the application is started, but you can also change this.